# How to use the EF Designer in Visual Studio 2022 and EF 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2022, designer

Latest stable for both.

I've successfully scaffolded and then migrated (to get ASPNetUser tables over to the database). Work policy is Database-First. The solution consists of web app and worker service projects using shared models in a Folder and this works well.

Now I've made changes to the tables, and would like to update the models. Obviously migrating is the opposite of what I want, and if I scaffold I may overwrite our own additions (to e.g. OnConfiguration, used services, etc) - is this correct?

It seems EF Designer will let me do this, but I'm not able to find how to even open the EF Designer shown in many answers to the question.

Do these [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/what-is-new/) (see "EF Designer Support") suggest that it's deprecated, and is the workaround recommended?

Comment: I use a database project in Visual Studio and do a schema comparison between the two. Use the generated script to determine which models changed.

Comment: Scaffold-DbContext ignores -OutputDir if it is a relative path, and requires project references to be added that is not required for scaffolding. It also silently fails adding default values: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22842

This happens also even after previously succeeding in doing so, using the same user account with the same rights.It's a tool that cannot be trusted for work, so that best practice should be to manually add each change to the database as code. Likely, EF Designer and similar plug-ins use Scaffold-DbContext and so cannot be used for work either.

Answer (score 0):

Use partial classes/methods for any changes, so they do not get overwritten, and then use

```
-Force
```

(or have a look at EF Core Power Tools)

There is no "EF designer" for EF Core